# Spring Ajax Cannot find Controller handler

Tags: ajax, spring, controller

I am new to programming with AJAX. Currently, I am getting a 404 error code but I'm not quite sure what's going wrong and if anyone could help I would be very grateful. I am trying to use a user input to get access to the database. I am using AJAX to send data to the controller but the AJAX request isn't being picked up by the controller. If anyone could help I would be very grateful.

The error code is :

> jquery.min.js:6 GET http://localhost:8080/GCSE/student_report/7days_report/?username=v 404

Here is my ajax code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#username").keyup(function(){
     console.log($("#username").val());
     $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url:
    "/GCSE/student_report/7days_report/?username="+$("#username").val(),
     success: function(result){
     $("#name").html(result);
     }
     });
    });
 });
```

And here is the controller code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/GCSE/student_report/7days_report/{username}")
public ModelAndView getGCSEReportBy_JSON() {
 Report GCSE = ps.getReportsWithUsernamePrefix(username);
 return new ModelAndView("index", "data", GCSE);
}
```

The PS Service code

```
    @Autowired
private ReportRepository rrRepo;
public Iterable<Report> getAllReports(){
    return rrRepo.findAll();
}
```

Cheers Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url in Ajax should be:

`"/GCSE/student_report/7days_report/" + $("#username").val()`

In method, you can extract username using method signature

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/GCSE/student_report/7days_report/{username}")
public ModelAndView getGCSEReportBy_JSON(@PathVariable String username)
```

If you want to use link that you created, then method should be

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/GCSE/student_report/7days_report")
public ModelAndView getGCSEReportBy_JSON(@RequestParam String username)
```

@PathVariable extracts variable from URL path, where variables are defined using `{}` and in path.
@RequestParam extracts variables that are defined after `?` in URL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, when I run it now I get an error code 500. I changed the first part to what you said and used the path variable one.

Comment: Error code 500 is the internal server error. Check spring console log for info. I am not sure which template engine do you use, for example thymeleaf or similar, but probably returning empty ModelAndView object would cause error.

Comment: Thank you @Boris, I have now added in my modelAndView with my parameters and I still get the error, I have updated the solution with the updated code.

Comment: @JeffereyJohnSmith if you could paste somewhere error log that you are receiving, so I can take a look, maybe I can see what is wrong.

Comment: Hey, turns out I was just an idiot and it couldn't find the return view, so it was finding the controller, so your code worked. Thank you for your help, I will mark as answer :)